# Apache URL rewrite without changing hostname

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

When  a user access the following URL http://adomain.com/bhfiuxeyriuxx

i want the content from the following URL to be displayed => 
http://anotherdomain.com/backoffice/index.php?controller=AdminSupplyOrdersSW&token=f5be89c23119d500a3e72e4f989cc607

The URL on the browser should be http:// adomain.com/bhfiuxeyriuxx without redirecting

Is this possible?

Or Should i use domain masking?

Comment: The easiest would be to use apaches `mod_proxy` and configure a "reverse proxy" for this. Take a look at the excellent documentation.

Comment: Query parameters are no problem for the proxy module. This is clearly stated in the documentation and shown in examples. A short test on your side will show the same.